# Spring logBack multiple appender not working in single spring profile

Tags: spring-boot, spring-logback

Using Spring log back configuration for logging application log but facing issue with multiple appender in single spring profile.

Above spring log back configuration not working on unix host but working in my workspaces.

Below is the sample config

```
<springProfile name="Profile1”>

    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml"/>

  <root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
  </root>
</springProfile>
```

Only one appender is working i.e. File appender but both are not working.

Can we achieve multiple appended via single spring boot profile?

Please let me know what can we tried?

Want both appenders to be working with single spring boot profile.